# Difference rabbitMQ and Load Balancer

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, load-balancing

What is the difference between a messaging queue like RabbitMQ and a load balancer?

They both use the same logic of sending data in a serial fashion to available workers, but people seem to treat them like different things.

Answer (score 0):

A load balancer distributes connections evenly across the servers that make up a service to allow the service to sale horizontally and prevent disruptions when issues occur on individual servers.

A messaging service like rabbitmq allows a set of servers to publish data for another set of servers, while providing mechanisms to link those consumers and publishers together in various ways and ensure the data exchange is easy to configure and runs smoothly. I would argue they are not similar because consuming occurs asynchronously from publishing, as well as solving different problems.